# Why does the Type attribute of a static class show "abstract" in C#?

Tags: c#

Main Code:

```
public class ReflectionsDemo
{
    public void demo()
    {
        Type t = typeof(StaticClassDemo);
        Console.WriteLine(t.Attributes);
    
    }
}
```

**StaticClassDemo** is just a static class with a couple of static methods.

Output:
**AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public, Abstract, Sealed**

I understand that a static class can't be marked as an abstract class, but why it is having abstract as an attribute?

Comment: Confusing question wording.. So if you *"**don't** understand that it **won't** be"* it effectively means the same as "do understand that it will be" - so if you understand why it's a static class, what is the question?

Comment: These are CLR type attributes that nail down the behavior of a static C# class, even if the class is used in another language.  TypeAttributes.Abstract prevents the `new` statement from working, so you can't create an object of the class.  TypeAttributes.Sealed closes the backdoor, it stops deriving another (non-static) class from the type and thus getting the constructor to run.

Comment: @CaiusJard sorry for the bad english, updated that confusing sentence now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Abstract" sort of means "you cannot create an instance of this type"

"Sealed" means "you cannot inherit from this type"

Together, if you squint a little, they describe a static class.

The "[static class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)" feature was not available from the start, so I assume that rather than introduce a new attribute to describe it, the creators used the combination of these existing attributes.

In fact, the [language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#static-classes) says:

> A static class may not include a `sealed` or `abstract` modifier. Note, however, that since a static class cannot be instantiated or derived from, it behaves as if it was both sealed and abstract.